# Maintaining session information while using Observer Design Pattern in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, observer-pattern, observers

I am using the `Observable` and `Observer` classes from `java.util` package.

I have the following in my `Observable` class

```
public class IfxHistoryObservable extends Observable {
public void inputHistoryUpdate(
            SomeDto inputHistoryDto,
            String type) {

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("changeType", type);
        data.put("changedData", inputHistoryDto);

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(data);
    }
}
```

**Observer** class

```
public class IfxHistoryObserver implements Observer {

 @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object param) {

JSONObject data = (JSONObject)param;
SomeDto dto = data.get("changedData")

ifxSecurityService.filterDataBasedOnUserSession(dto) //query regarding this line

}
}
```

whenever any dto is added or updated, I want to notify all the users.
However, before I notify I want it to pass through a security service where it checks if the user has the authority to view.

We are using Spring in Java. When I call the security function to check for authority, I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.ifxSecurityService': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

The scope for `ifxSecurityService` bean is request and it can't be changed.

I checked that the user session information is not available inside the observer. What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: What do you call a user session? how do you intend to check if the user has the appropriate rights?

Comment: @MauricePerry  I edited the question